# ¿Cómo aumentar el tamaño del área de trabajo de workbench?

Tags: mysql

Pues sucede que recien comencé a trabajar en workbench, pero no sé de qué manera puedo hacer más grande el lienzo de trabajo, ya que mi modelo es demasiado grande y ya no cabe. No encuentro cómo hacerlo. De antemano, gracias.

Comment: **Listo ya encontré cómo se hace, es en la opción Model>Diagram Propeties and Size**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay una opción en model (me parece) ahí se ven unos cuadros. Seleccionas los cuadros de alto por los de ancho y listo

Comment: Muchas gracias Daniel, recien hace un momento buscando en algunos foros pude encontrar la misma opción. Un fuerte abrazo.

Comment: Por nada. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

si deseas redimensionar el área de trabajo en el diagrama entidad relación te vas a la opción Modelo --> Propiedades de Diagrama y Tamaño